# Matplotlib - understanding color values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found a piece of code which is passing a 1D Numpy array to MatplotLib. The values of array are either 1 or 0, but the graph plotted has colours as yellow or purple. I am unable to find any documentation around it.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_observations = 5000

x1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, .85],[.85, 1]], num_observations) # mean, covariance
x2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 4], [[1, .85],[.85, 1]], num_observations)

features = np.vstack((x1, x2)).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.hstack((np.zeros(num_observations),np.ones(num_observations)))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.scatter(features[:, 0], features[:, 1],
        c = labels, alpha = .4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can anyone explain how we are getting the colors as yellow and violet? Relevant Documentation would also help.

Comment: The color is determined by the colormap used in `scatter`. By default this is `viridis` (`plt.scatter(..., cmap="viridis")`). Use a [different one](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) of your choice, or create your own if you do not like it.

Answer (score 1):

Its using the default `viridis` colormap, and so purple represents 0 and yellow represents 1. See here for more about colormaps: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html.

Adding a colorbar helps here. Adding one to your example is easy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_observations = 5000

x1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, .85],[.85, 1]], num_observations) # mean, covariance
x2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 4], [[1, .85],[.85, 1]], num_observations)

features = np.vstack((x1, x2)).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.hstack((np.zeros(num_observations),np.ones(num_observations)))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
p = plt.scatter(features[:, 0], features[:, 1],
        c = labels, alpha = .4)

plt.colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: in a "data presentation" sense, the colour bar should be removed from this example as it does more harm than good. It appears that the dataset is discreet; all colours other than yellow and purple are irrelevant.